# Jquery response, only single object returned while loop fails

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to return an array of surnames from a json query to form part of a section which can be chosen by a user.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1',
type: "GET",
success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    original = convState.current;
    State.current.next = State.newState({
       type: 'select',
       question: ['Please select'],
       answer: [{text: [response.data[0].last_name], value: 'true'}],
});
```

The current result only returns the one surname `bluth` from the json which can be found at https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1

If I try and add a loop to access the array, absolutely nothing happens. The html page just waits for something to happen, which never happens.
Can some please help met rectify the loop, I am not sure where and how I should add it. I tried here, but then the page waits for nothing to ever happen.

```
    var len = data.length;
      for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        answer: [{text: [response.data[i].last_name], value: 'true'}],
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check your console log to see if any errors are occurring. The provided `for` loop did not work for me. However, the AJAX query works and I am able to loop through the array by modifying your `for` loop. Look at my example code.

EDIT: I understand what is happening in your code. You tried implementing a `for` loop within creating an object (which does not work). My sample code aggregates all of the last names into an array and then uses that for creating a new state. I'm not sure if you wanted multiple new states, or one state with multiple answers.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1',
    type: "GET",
    success: function (response) {
        let data = response.data;
        let array = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            let account = data[i];
            let info = {text: [account.last_name], value: 'true'};
            array.push(info);
        }
        console.log(array);
        // Now do something with the array...
        original = convState.current;
        State.current.next = State.newState({
            type: 'select',
            question: ['Please select'],
            answer: array
        }
});
```

Or if you would like to using the `map` function to simplify array creation, you can do the following.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1',
    type: "GET",
    success: function (response) {
        let data = response.data;
        let array = data.map((account) => Object.create({text: [account.last_name], value: 'true'}));
        console.log(array)
        // Now do something with the array...
        original = convState.current;
        State.current.next = State.newState({
            type: 'select',
            question: ['Please select'],
            answer: array
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me modify it quickly to my code and see how it works! Just a slightly off topic question, can I predefine `last_name` in a variable and the use it as `let info = {text: [account.(var_name_here)]` instead of having to hardcode `last_name`?

Comment: and it worked!! Thanks man, see edit in my question with the screenshot. If you have any ideas on that variable, that would be a life saver.

Comment: I believe I know what you mean. If you want to dynamically access properties in an object, use the indexor with a string as the key.

For example: `account.last_name` becomes `account["last_name"]`. These are equivalent. Look at this link for more info: https://dmitripavlutin.com/access-object-properties-javascript/

Comment: Thanks. So what I want to do is to use html to ask user what he wants. So if user then inserts `last_name` it will display the list of surnames, if the user defines `first_name` it should define collect that. but I think it gets more complicated because if the user then selects a surname, the ajax variable should then change to the new value. Let's say `smith` which on submit will get another part of the ajax query. So pretty much need to update what the ajax call needs to collect from the link. In othwer words the `last_name` should not be hard coded as `[account.last_name]`.

Comment: I suppose that is quite a question so I would need ask a new question.. I will link it here.

Comment: Here is the [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64150174/use-dynamic-variable-from-html-and-update-state-in-ajax-jquery)

Comment: Hi Again. I managed to store the variable succesfully and use it. I need to find a way to update that variable with the next selection from the result. If you get a chance to look at the other question, I would greatly appreciate it. You only need to focus on the `Final edit` as the rest is not really relevant.